# Mongodb with Php 5.5.8

Tags: php, mongodb

I have PHP 5.5.8, MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012), x86 and I cant make the mongoDb work.

It won't accept any DLL; either it explains that entry point of DLL is bad, or just drops an alert box with empty message.

Answer (score 1):

You need a dll that was compiled with your php version. you might have a dll that was compiled with an earlier version.